# How to call permission sheet again CoreMotion

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, core-motion

I have been using some CoreMotion (pedometer) data in an app that I am writing. Early on I granted the app permission to the data and everything is working well.

Now I am going to write the part that asks the user for permission but since I have already granted the permissions the dialog never comes up and I can not test the behavior except on a new phone every time (not feasible).

Is there a way to delete from iOS all knowledge of the app so it looks like a first time install again?

Comment: You may want to pick an answer if any worked for you, and tick *This answer was useful* to let others know

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to reset permission to access Motion data, you could tap "Reset Location & Privacy" in Settings > General > Reset.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app from the device and install it again.

Or go to settings, find you app in the list and uncheck switch representing motion data.

Comment: Removing the permission won't prompt the user again; it is just treated as if they have denied permission. Deleting the app is the answer

Comment: You're right, there will be no alert, but you can check granted permissions in code and provide link to Settings where user can enable permissions again.  So that if user denied permissions for the first time it will be easier to enable them back.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting app may not be enough. Try this:

1. Delete your app from the device.
2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
4. Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

Combining all answers, from soft to radical:

1. Uncheck the permission in Settings. That works for motion, location, healthkit, etc.
2. Delete the App. This is generally enough for all case scenario
3. **Simulator**: *Reset Contents and Settings...*
   You can do that from command line, too.
4. **Device**: *Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings*
   That is what a development device is for.